# Count number of letters in a string from vector C++

Tags: c++

I'm having some trouble figuring this problem and I was wondering if anyone could tell me what's going wrong. Essentially, I need to take however many strings (until the console stops), push them to a vector, take all the strings from said vector and turn them into one big string, then count the number of each specific character in that string.

For example, the inputs "Hello" "hello" "Stack" "stAck" would output

a: 2

c: 2

e: 2

h: 2

k: 2

l: 4

o: 2

s: 2

t: 2

Here's what I have so far. I've managed to pass all the strings from the vector into one big string, but when I try and count the number of letters in the string something goes wrong and I'm not sure what.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
using namespace std;

int numA(string s){
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++){
        if(s[i] == 'a' || s[i] == 'A'){
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

int numB(string s){
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++){
        if(s[i] == 'b' || s[i] == 'B'){
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

int main(){

    vector<string> words;
    string str;

    while(cin >> str){
        cin >> str;
        words.push_back(str);
    }
    str = accumulate(begin(words), end(words), str);


    cout << str << endl;
    cout << "a: " << numA(str) << endl;
    cout << "b: " << numB(str) << endl;
}
```

Right now I'm only testing for the amount of A's, a's, B's and b's, but for some reason, sometimes it passes out the right number but other times it'll output a few less than it's supposed to, or sometimes none at all, even if there's clearly an a or b in it.

I have a feeling it's something to do with the accumulate, but I'm not sure otherwise. If anyone can explain to me what could possibly be going wrong I'd really appreciate the help. Thanks!

Comment: What does your C++ textbook tell you about what the third parameter to this specific overload of `std::accumulate` does, and why do you think you need it?

Comment: Are you sure there isn't another way to solve this problem...writing every num_a, num_A, num_b, num_B, num_c, num_C, etc... function will work, but surely there is a better way? that you could keep track of all the letters that you have seen and incrementing the value?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik we don't have a textbook in that class. he kinda just goes over different examples and then tells us to figure the labs out using those examples. honestly im not sure why, or even if, i need accumulate, i just looked on the internet for a good hour or so and thats the one thing that did what i needed.

Comment: @jackw11111 im sure there is, but i have no clue what that way would be.

Comment: The only way to effectively learn C++, the most complicated general purpose programming language in use today, is with a good textbook. You are not going to learn anything from random Youtube video or a web site. Anyone can upload a video to youtube or create a web page that says anything, whether it's right or wrong. If you find some random code on the Internet, and copy/paste it into your own code without fully understanding what it is and how it works, even if its description sounds similar it is very unlikely you will get useful results from that.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik i agree but for both levels of the class at my school there isn't a textbook associated. the only resources we're given are the examples of different problems he goes over and the tutoring center (which doesn't really even help). when i learned java last semester at a different school the textbook was basically a 2nd professor to me. always came in handy.

Comment: That is unfortunate. I can certainly believe that, and stories about woefully inadequate C++ instructors or classes are frequently mentioned here; but it is what it is, and there is no other answers except, perhaps, taking the initiative yourself to get a textbook and learn C++ on your own. It won't be easy, but it is possible.

Comment: it is unfortunate :/. i try and look at the bright side of the situation though. because he doesn't really give us adequate resources, i resort to this website and google as a whole so it teaches me new, and a lot of the times, simpler ways of solving problems. do you have any recommendations for (cheap, lol) textbooks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues you are missing. The primary one is that whenever you need to know the frequency within which any number of objects occur, you simply need a *Frequency Array* that contains the number of elements (one for each object in the range you need to measure), with each element initially set to zero. When you are simply looking at character frequency, a simple array of 26 `int` (one for each character in the alphabet) is all that is needed. The ASCII value allows a simple mapping from character to array-index.

If you have a more complicated type that doesn't provide a simple way of mapping `value => index`, then you can use something that allows storing that number of pairs, like a `std::unordered_set` or similar.

Here mapping characters [ASCII Table and Description](http://www.asciitable.com/) provides a simple way to map characters to array-index. Additionally, since you are ignoring case, just convert all characters to either *upper* or *lower* before mapping the index.

Putting it altogether, you could do something similar to:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cctype>

#define NCHAR 26

int main () {
    
    std::string s {};                       /* string */
    std::vector<std::string> vs {};         /* vector of strings */
    int lower[NCHAR] = {0};                 /* frequency array - initialized all zero */
    
    while (std::cin >> s)                   /* read each word */
        vs.push_back(s);                    /* add to vector */
    
    if (vs.size() == 0)                     /* validate at least 1 word stored */
        return 1;
    
    for (const auto& w : vs)                /* for each word in vector of strings */
        for (const auto& c : w)             /* for each char in word */
            if (isalpha(c))                 /* if [a-zA-Z] */
                lower[tolower(c)-'a']++;    /* convert tolower, increment index */
        
    for (int i = 0; i < NCHAR; i++)         /* loop over frequency array */
        if (lower[i])                       /* if element not zero, output result */
            std::cout << (char)(i+'a') << ": " << lower[i] << '\n';
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

Using a simple *heredoc* to feed the words in your example to the program would result in the following:

```
$ ./bin/vectstr_frequency << 'eof'
> Hello
> hello
> Stack
> stAck
> eof
a: 2
c: 2
e: 2
h: 2
k: 2
l: 4
o: 2
s: 2
t: 2
```

The frequency array is a frequently used mapping to determine the occurrences of whatever set of objects you may be dealing with. It may take a bit to digest how mapping a value to an array index and then incrementing the element at that index produces the frequency of occurrences -- but the light-bulb will wink on and it will make perfect sense.

(based on your comments, and to ensure the responses are not wiped on a comment cleanup by Sam, the following additional information is provided as part of the answer)

**Frequency Array Explained**

To help wrap your head around how the frequency array is populated and how values are mapped to indexes and then indexes mapped back to values, take `char ch;` to hold the current character. If `ch == 'd';` Then `ch - 'a'` maps the current character `'d'` to the index `3`. How? The [ASCII Table](http://www.asciitable.com/), `'d' - 'a'` is `100 - 97` which is `3`. (so your mapping simply subtracts the value for the first object in the range from the current value, ensuring the first object in your range maps to the first element of your frequency array)

When outputting the results, for example `for (int i = 0; i < NCHAR; i++)`, `i` represents the frequency array index which will be `0, 1, 2, ...` So to map in the opposite direction, the character represented by the index will be `i + 'a'`. E.g., when the index is `3`, you have `3 + 97` which is `100` which corresponds to the ASCII character `'d'`. So you subtract `'a'` to map to index, and add that same offset `'a'` (97) to the index to map the index back to the character (value in your range).

If you look, you are just subtracting whatever is needed to map the first value in the range back to zero (the first index in your frequency array), and then going back from index to value, you are just adding that same offset to the index.

**To Determine the Frequency of Characters `' '` to `'/'`**

You have 16 continual values in your range, the ASCII characters from `' '` (32) to `'/'` (47). so you need a frequency array with 16-elements, e.g. `int punct[16] = {0};` to measure the occurrences of the punctuation in that range. Then you can test `if (' ' <= c && c <= '/') { /* process the punctuation */ }` where you would map the character to index with `c - ' '` and then you would map the index back to character with `i + ' '`. Works the same way for any consecutive range of objects.

But note, in this case you can't use `std::cin >> s` to read each string, you must use `getline(std::cin, s)` to read a *line-at-a-time*. Why? Your new range includes spaces and `>>` stops reading when it encounters a `space`. So using `std::cin >> s;`, you will never read any spaces.

Changing input to use `getline()` and adding the `punct[]` frequency array, you could do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cctype>

#define NPUNC 16        /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define NCHAR 26

int main () {
    
    std::string s {};                       /* string */
    std::vector<std::string> vs {};         /* vector of strings */
    int lower[NCHAR] = {0},                 /* frequency array - initialized all zero */
        punct[NPUNC] = {0};                 /* frequency array - for ' ' - '/' */
    
    while (getline (std::cin, s))           /* read each line */
        vs.push_back(s);                    /* add to vector */
    
    if (vs.size() == 0)                     /* validate at least 1 line stored */
        return 1;
    
    for (const auto& l : vs)                /* for each line in vector of strings */
        for (const auto& c : l)             /* for each char in line */
            if (isalpha(c))                 /* if [a-zA-Z] */
                lower[tolower(c)-'a']++;    /* convert tolower, increment index */
            else if (' ' <= c && c <= '/')  /* if ' ' through '/' */
                punct[c-' ']++;             /* increment corresponding punct index */
    
    for (int i = 0; i < NPUNC; i++)         /* loop over punct frequency array */
        if (punct[i])                       /* if element not zero, output result */
            std::cout << (char)(i+' ') << ": " << punct[i] << '\n';
    
    std::cout.put('\n');
    
    for (int i = 0; i < NCHAR; i++)         /* loop over frequency array */
        if (lower[i])                       /* if element not zero, output result */
            std::cout << (char)(i+'a') << ": " << lower[i] << '\n';
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ echo 'My *#$/#%%!! Dog Has Fleas!!' | ./bin/vectstr_frequency+punct
 : 4
!: 4
#: 2
$: 1
%: 2
*: 1
/: 1

a: 2
d: 1
e: 1
f: 1
g: 1
h: 1
l: 1
m: 1
o: 1
s: 2
y: 1
```

(**note:** if you use `printf` in bash instead of `echo`, then `"%%"` will be counted as a single `'%'` -- make sure you understand why (`man 3 printf` will do))

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me! Thank you so much!!!! I am interested in how it works though. So basically instead of converting all the vector inputs into a string, it pushes them into an array and then assigns each character it's own index? What do you mean by incrementing the element, though?

Comment: The vector holds each of the strings (words). The range based `for` loops loop over each word (outer loop) and then inner loop loops over each character in the current word. "Incrementing the element" means this. For the alphabet, the element indexes of the frequency array are mapped `0 - 'a'`, `1 - 'b'`, `2 - 'c'`, ... and so on. So if the current character is an `'a'` element `0` is incremented (meaning 1 - `'a'` was counted). After you do the same for all the characters in each word, the frequency array holds the frequency that each character appeared.

Comment: Take `char ch` to hold the current character. If `ch = 'd';` Then `ch - 'a'` maps the current character `'d'` to the index `3`. How? The [ASCII Table](http://www.asciitable.com/), `'d' - 'a'` == `100 - 97` == `3`. When outputting the results, `for (int i = 0; i < NCHAR; i++)`, `i` will be `0, 1, 2, ...` So to map in the opposite direction the character represented by the index will be `i + 'a'`. E.g., when the index is `3`, you have `3 + 97` which is `100` which corresponds to the ASCII character `d`. So you subtract `'a'` to map to index, and add `'a'` to map back to character.

Comment: ohhh ok. now say i wanted to also include the special characters like "space" through '/'. could you implement a way to check for those using this method? i guess along with other inputs like numbers inside the string, etc. i know isalpha checks for letters, but is there a similar method for special characters and numbers as well?

Comment: Ok, you have 16 elements  in your range, the ASCII characters from `' '` (32) to `'/'` (47). so you just create `int punct[16] = {0};` as your frequency array to measure the occurrences of the punctuation in that range. Then you can test `if (' ' <= c && c <= '/') { /* process the punctuation */ }` where you would map the character to index with `c - ' '` and then you would map the index back to character with `i + ' '`. Works for any consecutive range of objects `:)`. Go run [frequency array annotated](https://paste.opensuse.org/14522580) which adds output to help cement the process.

Comment: If you look, you are just subtracting whatever is needed to map the first character in the range back to zero (the first index in your frequency array), and then going back from index to character, you are just adding that same offset to the index `:)`

Comment: (but note, you can't use `std::cin >> s` to read each string anymore, you have to use `getline(std::cin, s)` to read a line at a time... Why? Your new range to measure includes spaces and `>>` stops reading when it encounters a space.... So you will never count any spaces...) Let me know if you get struck there and I can post an update.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much, I can see where frequency arrays will come in handy!